# Understanding Cubit/Bloc state management

Tags: flutter, bloc, cubit

I'm new to flutter and I have experience in web application using state managements like Redux or Vuex where the initial state of a module might be something like:

```
{
  value1: 0,
  value2: 10,
  aBool: false,
  aString: 'Hello'
}
```

Then based on Reducers or Mutations we can update a single or multiple properties of the state.

Now, learning Flutter I decided to use Bloc/Cubit and online I cannot find the right answer to my problem, even because the majority of the example are always based on the crappy counter app and never on a more realistic scenario.

All I can see is something based on 4 states in Bloc: initial, loading, success and error.

This is fine when fetching data from an API, but what if my state has also more properties?

how to update those properties?

Actually I created my test Cubit to fetch something from my API, it works. Now I wish to add more properties on the state and update it based on actions, how can I do that?

Example state:

```
@freezed
abstract class TestState with _$TestState {
  const factory TestState.initial() = _Initial;
  const factory TestState.loading() = _Loading;
  const factory TestState.success(UserData user) = _Success;
  const factory TestState.error(String message) = _Error;
}
```

Example Cubit:

```
class TestCubit extends Cubit<TestCubit> {
  TestCubit(this._testClient)
      : super(TestState.initial());
  final TestClient _testClient;

  String greet = 'Hi';

  Future<void> testFetchData() async {
     ...
     emit(TestState.success(testData));
     ...
  }
}
```

I can successfully handle the varioud initial, loading, etc... states.

I can correctly watch at the `greet` property: `context.read<TestCubit>().greet`

How should I now update that value with `'hello!'`?

```
// TestCubit
updateGreet(String text) {
  emit(I don't know); 
}
```

I omitted all my various tries to update that value.

Thanks

Comment: You'd better to move `greet` from your Cubit to State. Blocs and Cubits are not to store data properties, use State for that purpose. To handle more complicated state than enums or sealed classes you can use equatable class as data model of your state with `copy()` method. Unfortunately I don't know whether code generation suits for it or not, I don't use freezed. Guess that it suites. Anyway you can check my pet project if you need working example without code generation - https://github.com/TortikiDev/mobile-app

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at your project!